# How does vasomotor and bronchomotor reactions equilibrate local blood flow to correspond local ventilation?

Tags: physiology, blood-circulation, respiration

I am trying to find some figure(s) to explain this.
There is probably better name for "bronchomotor" reaction.
They seem to opposite terms and actually affecting same things (alveolar diameter/tone); one increasing, while the other decreasing.

I am been reading Pocock and Guyton but I am not happy in any any figures.

Which figures can you use to answers this question?

Comment: Maybe this is due to my limited anatomical background, but I don't really understand your question. And how should we find better figures when we don't know the ones you have?

Comment: I have not found any good picture. Probably, you cannot show this in one picture which I am trying to do. I will post some separate pictures about these two processes tomorrow evening.